# Cakephp 3.0 Truncating body in View

Tags: cakephp-3.0, truncate

im trying to limit my body to 20 characters in view but im not sure how to do it. Can anyone help me? Thank you

```
<h2 class="text-center"><?= h($article->title) ?>     
<html class="text-center"><?= $article->body ?></html>
<h2 class="text-center"><?= h($article->created) ?></h2>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `TextHelper`:

```
<?= $this->Text->truncate($article->body, 20) ?>
```